# Apache web server configuration with a DNS server Linux 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, configuration, apache-httpd, dns

I need to configure a Apache web server with a DNS server, it can be a simple local server configuration just to practice and see how a DNS server resolves a URL to an ip address and connects to a web server. I already have LAMP installed on my computer but I don't know how or where to start with the DNS server.

If there are any tutorials similar to what Iam trying to do I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

[BIND](http://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/) is one of the best DNS server in the world, you can use Bind to achieve your goal.

For configuration purpose here some useful sites:

Server World: (For Ubuntu)

- [DNS](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_10.04&p=dns)
- [Web](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_10.04&p=httpd)

Linux Home Networking:

- [DNS](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch18_:_Configuring_DNS#.VAeUIWPhUX4)
- [Web](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch20_:_The_Apache_Web_Server#.VAeUOmPhUX4)

To use BIND with web server here is a useful [Link](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-webserver-with-bind-and-apache-centos5).

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of manuals, even from Ubuntu. The Ubuntu Community Wiki is a good place to start, for example. There's this topic titled: [BIND 9 Server Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIND9ServerHowto).